# How do I change the shape of the background or make it transparent on popup.html for Chrome Extensions?

Tags: javascript, html, css, google-chrome-extension, popup

I making a Chrome Extension. How do you make the background transparent or just change the shape of it.

popup.html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Ellipses</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css">
</head>
<body background="none">
    <div class="outside-frame">
        <dir class="inside-frame">
            <h1>hello</h1>
        </dir>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

styles.css:

```
.outside-frame{
    background-color: rgb(32, 32, 32);
    border-top-left-radius: 5px;
    border-top-right-radius: 5px;
    border-bottom-left-radius: 5px;
    border-bottom-right-radius: 5px;
}
```

manifest.json:

```
{   
    "manifest_version": 3,
    "name":"Test Extension",
    "version": "1.0.0",
    "description": "pass",
    "content_scripts": [
        {
            "matches": ["<all_urls>"],
            "js": ["Content.js"]
        }
    ],
    "action": {
        "default_popup": "popup.html"
    }
}
```

I tried to do this in the styles.css file:

```
body{
    background: none;
}
```

Comment: Is this what you want? `body {
  background-color: transparent;
}`

Comment: There is no way to change shape of Chrome extension popup window or make it transparent

Comment: You can add your UI as a DOM element into the web page. Many extensions are doing it.